# How to download files in folder other then the download folder using Protractor?

Tags: automated-testing, protractor, chromedriver, uiautomation, nodejs

Using the following configuration, files are always saved in the download folder instead of the folder set for `default_directory`.

```
'capabilities': {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {
        'prefs': {
            'download': {
                'prompt_for_download': false,
                'directory_upgrade': true,
                'default_directory': 'src/test/javascript/e2e/downloads'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The ChromeDriver documentation states "*Relative paths do not always work. For best result, use full path instead.*". Explanation why it's not always working is lacking though. Using an absolute path should fix the issue. Detailed information can be found in the links below.

**ChromeDriver documentation**
https://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities

**Answer on Stack Overflow**
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27922587/setting-chromedriver-preferences-on-protractor-tests

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working fine , which protractor version are you using. Try using full path as mentioned in other answer and also try replacing CHromeoptions with googchromeOptions if first is nt working (new protractor version everything should work fine with justt chromeoption):

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5292

```
'capabilities': {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'goog:chromeOptions': {
        'prefs': {
            'download': {
                'prompt_for_download': false,
                'directory_upgrade': true,
                'default_directory': 'D:\\MyProjects\\protractor\\newproj\\New folder'
            }
        }
    }
},
```